# О смысле кода для разделения на К групп

Tags: python

Когда выборка мала, для обучения модели можно поделить её на несколько частей и посчитать среднее для всех частей.

```
k = 4
num_val_samples = len(train_data) // k
num_epochs = 100
all_scores = []
```

Поделили. У нас есть переменная, я. частным к длине массива.

```
for i in range(k):
val_data = train_data[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
val_targets = train_targets[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1)
* num_val_samples]
```

Но далее мы вырезаем промежуток для каждого элемента делителя от индекса, кратного частному, до следующего индекса. Т.е., если не ошибаюсь (скажем к=4), берём первый и второй, 26й и 27й, 51 и 52, 76 и 77й. Но i+1 < k, мы точно не охватим всего, даже половины. нет? Это данные проверочные, у нас нет задачи загнать их всех в модель, но зачем так изощрённо их выбирать?

```
partial_train_data = np.concatenate(
[train_data[:i * num_val_samples],
train_data[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]],
axis=0)
```

далее мы склеиваем все индексы со смещением на 1 для каждого делителя. Получается, проверка модели пойдёт для каждой группы len/(k+1) вводных с 2 проверочными, нет? почему просто нельзя было случано выбрать проверочный набор? спасибо